# HTTP 500 after upgrading to DNN 7

Tags: .net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I am working on a project which was previously on DNN 6. Because of security reasons the DNN framework need to be upgraded to `DNN 7`. To that I firstly upgraded it to `6.2.8`, website was working fine without any issues. 
Then after upgrading to `DNN 7.3.2` it gives a `500 error` when I try to login.

In the exception, it says that `EnterpriseLibrary.Validation` file cannot be found. Can someone please help me to solve this problem.

Here is the stack trace,

> DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.PageLoadException: Exception has been
>   thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
>   Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation, Version=3.1.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Can you add more context about the code that gives the error? It will help users answer your question faster and better. Thanks.

Comment: I couldn't find the location that the error might be coming, it has to be something wrong with the DNN. I added the error which I'm getting. I can go to the login page but once I click login that error comes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by my own and I just had to install the correct version of the EnterpriseLibrary.Validation to support .Net v4.0.